# Store Mass amount of 'UK PostCode' Data PHP/Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony, csv

I am building and API based url using symfony to fetch data for Postcodes provided by

- [Code-Point Open](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/code-point-open.html)

So far in my build i have added around 121 CSV files that i then loop through persisting data to a schema - each file contains at least 16K Entires and i am currently storing each of the file contents into one massive table.

Here is the current code -

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Helper;

use AppBundle\Entity\Postcodes;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;


class DataProcessing extends Controller
{

public function structureData(array $fileNames, EntityManager $em)
{
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 86400);

    $filePathArray = [];
    foreach ($fileNames as $fileName) {
        $filePathArray[] = ['filePath' => getcwd() . "/web/postCodeData/" . $fileName];
    }


    foreach ($filePathArray as $filePath) {
        if (($handle = fopen($filePath['filePath'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $postCodeModel = new Postcodes();
                $postCodeModel->setPostcode($data[0]);
                $postCodeModel->setEastings($data[2]);
                $postCodeModel->setNorthings($data[3]);
                $em->persist($postCodeModel);
                $em->flush();
                echo 'Saved new product with id '.$postCodeModel->getId() . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }

    ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);

  }
}
```

The Above is being called through a Symfony Command - i thought this would be the best way to init an Inital Data Import this large - gets called from the following function

```
 public function importData()
{
    $this->dataProcessing->structureData(
        $this->dataCheck->checkData(),
        $this->entityManager
    );
}
```

I just dont feel great with how i'm storing all this data - I believe there must be a better way to tackle this - I am looking for anyone who has any ideas and in general more experience with storing such a large amount of data as its somthing ive evidently not had to tackle before

My thoughts for better structure was take the name of each file - they having the following common names relating to their file contents -

```
"ab.csv" => "Contains->"
         -> ""AB101AB",10,394235,806529,"S92000003","","S08000020","","S12000033","S13002842"
"
```

and for clarification another file would be along the lines of -

```
"al.csv" => "Contains->"
         -> ""AL1 1AG",10,515487,206498,"E92000001","E19000001","E18000006","E10000015","E07000240","E05004802""
"
```

So to take the first two letters from the file name and create a table in which i would then store the file contents into alone

for example "ab.csv" would spit data out to "{$prefixOfLetters}postcodes"

So that i would have a table structure similar to the following

Table Names

---

ab-postcode - 
   al-postcodes - 
   b-postcodes -

---

I am unsure if this is a good idea or not so any advice here would be great

Another point im looking to get some notes/advice on is improving the time it takes to write all this data - part of my hopes that separate tables would improve things so any input here would be great!

Thanks for taking to time to read and in advance for any comments help given!

Comment: Using [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) would almost certainly be more efficient for bulk loading the data; but there should be no problems with one large indexed database table, and that's generally better than multiple small tables where you need to determine which table your data is in using code logic

Comment: Also, you could drop table indexes before bulk insertion and recreate them afterwards, which could improve performance

Comment: Thank you @MarkBaker I will look onto the load data infile!